# Can we update multiple dropdown values by changing any one of selected value in free jqgrid 4.15.4

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid 4.15.4 in one of my application. I have one question regarding updating multiple columns dropdown value at one go.  I am using multiselect: true,option.

I have also learned about concurrency issue, but for now that is not an issue for me.

I have added a demo fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tygLjmde/.

```
$(function () {
"use strict";
var mydata = [
    { id: "10",  FirstName: "test", LastName: "TNT", Gender: "Male" },
     { id: "11",     FirstName: "test2",    LastName: "ADXC", Gender: "Male" },
     { id: "12",     FirstName: "test3",    LastName: "SDR", Gender: "Female" },
     { id: "13",     FirstName: "test4",    LastName: "234", Gender: "Male" },
     { id: "14",     FirstName: "test5",    LastName: "DAS", Gender: "Male" },
];
$("#list").jqGrid({
data: mydata,
   
    colNames: ['','Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Gender'],
     colModel: [
  {
            name: "act", template: "actions",
           formatoptions: {
               delbutton: false
         }
        },
        {
            label: "Id",
            name: 'Id',
            hidden: true,
            search: false,
        },
        {
            label: "FirstName",
            name: 'FirstName',
            searchoptions: {
                searchOperators: true,
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le','ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'],
            }, search: true,
        },
        {
            label: "LastName",
            name: 'LastName',
            searchoptions: {
                searchOperators: true,
                sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'ni', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc'],
            }, search: true,
        },

        {
            label: "Gender",
            name: 'Gender',
            search: true, 
            edittype: "select",editable: true,
            editoptions: {
            value: "Male:Male;Female:Female;" ,                                                                 
                        },
          stype: "select",
                editrules: {
                    custom: true,
                    custom_func: function (value, colName, iCol)                                                    {
                        alert("The value to validate: " +value);
                        return [true];
                    }
                    },
        },
        ],
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastsel) {
            jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);
            jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
            lastsel = id;
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function (id) {
        if ($('#list').getGridParam('records') === 0) {
           
            //$('#grid tbody').html("<div style='padding:6px;background:#D8D8D8;'>No records found</div>");
        }
        else {
            var lastsel = 0;
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#list').restoreRow(lastsel);
                jQuery('#list').editRow(id, true);
                lastsel = id;
              }
            }
        },
    
    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    loadonce: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    width: 'auto',
    height: '450px',
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    multiselect: true,
    cellEdit:true,
    emptyrecords: "No records to display",
    jsonReader:
    {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "Id"
    },

});
$('#list').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn", multipleSearch: true, searchOperators: true, search: true, loadFilterDefaults: true });
$('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", {
    search: false, // show search button on the toolbar
    add: false,
    edit: false,
    del: false,
    refresh: true,
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
});    
});
```

where you will see checkboxes in first column and Gender column consist dropdown with values. So let say if I have selected two rows and changing only one-row gender dropdown value.
So is this possible that other row gender column value gets changed automatically? If Yes then any demo/code changes suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You use cell editing in your demo. Thus you can use `afterSaveCell` callback to make some additional actions after changing the value. You can examine the value of `selarrrow` parameter, which contains the list of ids of selected rows, and to use `setCell` to change the value of the Gender column of the rows to the new value:

```js
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cmName, value, iRow, iCol) {
    var $self = $(this);

    if (cmName === "Gender") {
        $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow").forEach(function (id) {
            var item = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", id);
            if (id !== rowid && item.Gender !== value) {
                $self.jqGrid("setCell", id, iCol, value, false, false, true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/20wh9a7g/